# Proving that $P \subseteq NP,$ formally and using Turing Machines.

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

My question urges on proving that $P \subseteq NP.$ The definitions I am using follow below:

**Definition.** We define the set of languages $DTime$ as
$$ DTime(t(n)) = \{ L \colon \text{there is a deterministic decider of $L$ that runs in $\mathcal O(t(n))$}\},$$
where $t \colon \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0$. From here, we defined the class $P$ as
$$ P = \bigcup_{k \geqslant 0} DTime(n^k) $$

**Definition.** We define the set of languages $NTime$ as
$$ NTime(t(n)) = \{ L \colon \text{there is a non-deterministic decider of $L$ that runs in $\mathcal O(t(n))$}\},$$
where $t \colon \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0.$  From here, we define the class $NP$ as
$$ NP = \bigcup_{k \geqslant 0} NTime(n^k).$$

**The main objetive.** I am looking forward to show that $P \subseteq NP.$

**My attempt.** Consider an arbitrary language in the class $P$. Then, we can guarantee that there is a deterministic decider of $L$ that runs in $\mathcal O(n^k),$ for some $k \in \mathbb N_0.$ To prove that this same language is in $NP$, one should show that there exists a non-deterministic decider of $L$ that runs in $\mathcal O(n^p),$ for some non-negative integer $p$.

Let $M = (Q,\Sigma,\tau, \delta,s,F)$ be the deterministic decider of $L$ that we know exists and let $M_1 = (Q,\Sigma,\tau,\delta_1,s,F)$ be a non-deterministic decider such that it has the exact same states as $M$, and so on... . We define its transition function as follows: for every $q \in Q, a \in \tau$ such that $\delta(q,a)$ is defined:

$$ \delta_1(q,a) = \{ \delta(q,a) \}.$$

Obviously, $\mathcal L(M) = \mathcal L(M_1)$ and they also run in the same time.

**My doubts.** I am having a hard time proving (FORMALLY) that $\mathcal L(M) = \mathcal L(M_1)$ and that they run in the same time, altought it is clear in my intuition.

Comment: Your idea is correct. Essentially you want to show that a deterministic determiner is a non-deterministic determiner so that every element of DTime is an element of NTime.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes - I believe I understood what I was supposed to do here - I just can't see how to prove formally $\mathcal L(M_1) = \mathcal L(M)$ (obviously, here the idea here would be to take some $w \in \mathcal L(M)$ and show that $w \in \mathcal L(M_1)$ and vice-versa).

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. Let $M$ be a deterministic decider and show that it is a non-deterministic decider using the definition of non-deterministic decider. Having shown that for arbitrary $M$ conclude that DTime is a subset of NTime and note that, by definition, $P\subset NP$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Well,  every deterministic decider $M$ can be seen as a non-deterministic decider in the sense that the tree associated with it is a vertical line $(?)$

Comment: Right, so now look at the definitions. It follows directly that $P\subset NP$. Your professor may not accept the vertical line proof. You probably have to be more precise with defining each of the six components.

Comment: @JohnDouma And what would that be? A deterministic decider $M$ is a sextuple $M = (Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta,s,F).$ Define a non-deterministic decider $M' = (Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta',s,F)$ that has exactly the same components besides the transiction function. As I said in the post, define $\delta'(q,a) = \{ \delta(q,a) \}$, for every $q \in Q, a \in \Gamma$ s.t. $\delta(q,a)$ is defined. How does it follow that $M' = M?$

Comment: That shows that every deterministic machine is a non-deterministic machine. $P$ is the union of elements of DTime each of which is an element of NTime so $P\subset NP$. That should do it.

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks for your help @JohnDouma